# Line break description wordpress

Tags: custom-field, description

Currently in Wordpress 5.1, I create custom fields including a description field using the text editor of worpress, however I encounter a problem no line break is made.
Is there a function for the line break to work

Comment: Are you using code to create the custom fields? If so, it would help to include it in your question.

Comment: Excuse me https://hastebin.com/mofivivexi.xml

Answer (score 0):

You should use the filter to show the description. Try to replace $your_description with the custom field value.

```
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $your_description);
echo !empty($your_description) ? $content : __('Nothing to show!', 'your_textdomain');
```